# Declaring a Styles file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know which is the best way of implementing a Styles file inside Flutter with all my color information and Text-style.

Running through some tutorials some seems to use an abstract class and others use functions. Also the import is done differently.

Performance/Convenience/Organization-wise what is the best way to do this?

Or should I avoid doing this entirely and just declare everything as Themes instead?

- First method:

  `styles.dart` file imported as

  ```
  import 'styles.dart';
  ```

  styles.dart file:

  ```
  import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

  abstract class ThemeText {
    static const TextStyle progressHeader = TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        color: ThemeColor.bodyText,
        fontSize: 40,
        height: 0.5,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);
  }
  ```
- Second method:

  utils.dart file imported as:

  ```
  import './utils.dart' as utils;
  ```

  `utils.dart` content:

  ```
  TextStyle getProgressHeaderStyle() {
    return const TextStyle(
        color: ThemeColor.bodyText,
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: 40.0,
        height: 0.5);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**For the import part**, you can use one of the below, they have the same meaning:

```
import 'package:your_project_name/utils.dart';
import './utils.dart';
import 'utils.dart';
```

it just a matter of convention.

You should use `import 'package:your_project_name/utils.dart';` to classifying imported library from outside of your project. And use `import 'utils.dart';` for your internal library.

using `import './utils.dart';` feel superfluous to me. Seems that it use the unix file path convention which `./` means a current directory.

For the `as` keyword in the following line:

```
 import './utils.dart' as utils;
```

it means that you want to group all the code in `utils.dart` as `utils`. So, whenever you need to use the code from `utils.dart`, you need to use `utils` before calling the function in it. Something like this:

```
utils.getProgressHeaderStyle()
```

---

**For `styles.dart` and `utils.dart`**,

Using an abstract class and `const` variable is good way to organizing all your related style in a group. In your following code:

```
abstract class ThemeText {
  static const TextStyle progressHeader = TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      color: ThemeColor.bodyText,
      fontSize: 40,
      height: 0.5,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);
}
```

you're grouping the style as a group of ThemeText. Consider the following scenario: You need three progress styles for your **Text** header, body, and footer. So, you need to group all of them as a group of text. You can do the following then:

```
abstract class ThemeText {
  static const TextStyle progressHeader = TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 40,
      height: 0.5,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);

  static const TextStyle progressBody = TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 10,
      height: 0.5,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400);

  static const TextStyle progressFooter = TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 20,
      height: 0.5,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);
}
```

So, you now have three variables that you can access with:

```
ThemeText.progressHeader;
ThemeText.progressBody;
ThemeText.progressFooter;
```

You have one place for all the Text style properties now!

---

Now, how about using the `utils.dart` for organizing your style? Your `utils.dart` is the following:

```
TextStyle getProgressHeaderStyle() {
  return const TextStyle(
      color: ThemeColor.bodyText,
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 40.0,
      height: 0.5);
}
```

adding the body and footer will make it become this:

```
TextStyle getProgressHeaderStyle() {
      return const TextStyle(
          color: ThemeColor.bodyText,
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          fontSize: 40.0,
          height: 0.5);
    }

TextStyle getProgressBodyStyle() {
  return const TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 10,
      height: 0.5,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400);
}

TextStyle getProgressFooterStyle() {
  return const TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 20,
      height: 0.5,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);
}
```

where you can access all the function like this:

```
utils.getProgressHeaderStyle();
utils.getProgressBodyStyle();
utils.getProgressFooterStyle();
```

you can see that you're now accessing a group of method *not a **properties*** of styles.

You also have a small performance hits (though negligible) whenever you're calling a function.

Comment: Thanks so much, this answers perfectly my question. Indeed abstract classes seem way more useful.

Comment: Wonderful Explanation