# abstract class function not able to access anywhere in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, static-methods

I m trying to use text style using abstract function like this

```
import 'dart:ui';
abstract class AppStyles {
  TextStyle getNameStyle() {
  return  TextStyle(
    fontSize: 40.0,
   );
}
}
```

this style I m trying to access like this

```
const Text(
          'Welcome to Flutter app',
          style: AppStyles.getNameStyle(),
        ),
```

Refer to this example also

[Declaring a Styles file in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531969/declaring-a-styles-file-in-flutter)

But its says this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either create function static

```
abstract class AppStyles {
     static TextStyle getNameStyle() {
       return  TextStyle(
         fontSize: 40.0,
       );
     }
  }
```

or create subclass of `AppStyles` and instantiate it:

```
class AppStylesImpl extends AppStyles {}

const Text(
      'Welcome to Flutter app',
      style: AppStylesImpl().getNameStyle(),
    ),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer
i have tried this method but its says
 invalid constant value
the static method cant be accessed through an instance

Comment: remove const from Text

Answer (score 0):

Make function static:

```
  abstract class AppStyles {
     static TextStyle getNameStyle() {
       return  TextStyle(
         fontSize: 40.0,
       );
     }
  }
```

import correct library for TextStyle,

```
'package:flutter/material.dart'
```

not

```
'dart:ui'
```

Comment: it didnt work for me it says The argument type Textstyle cannot be assigned to paramter tye Textstyle?

Comment: @sarathi make sure you import correct library for TextStyle, 'package:flutter/material.dart', not 'dart:ui'